# Differences between pylibmc, dbm, and memcached in dogpile.cache

Tags: python, dogpile.cache

I am new to caching in Python and unable to understand the differences between `dogpile.cache.dbm`, `dogpile.cache.pylibmc`, and `dogpile.cache.memcached`. Could someone please explain it?

Answer (score 3):

`dogpile.cache` has unified interface for different caching backends – meaning that your data can be stored in different places, while library will provide you same functionality for all of them.

- `dbm` is for generic database backend
- `pylibmc` is for [memcached](https://memcached.org/) via [`pylibmc` client](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/)
- `memcached` is for same [memcached system](https://memcached.org/), but through different python driver – [`python-memchached`](https://pypi.org/project/python-memcached/)

You can see all available backends in [documentation](https://dogpilecache.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api.html#dogpile.cache.api.CacheBackend)